# Flying to Canada via London / Toronto from Mumbai: Do I require a transit visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, canada, airports, transit-visas

I am planning to travel to Canada (Ottawa) from Mumbai. I have Canada immigrant visa (Permanent Residence). I haven't yet received the PR card, and my port of entry is Ottawa.

I have two options,
1. Travel to Ottawa via Toronto
2. Travel to Ottawa via London

I want to know whether I would require a transit visa for for 1st option? Because, I already have a Canadian immigrant visa!

Also, will I require a transit UK visa, if I select option 2? I checked the below website of UK govt.

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no

Here it says the following exemption,

> Exemptions
>
> You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used
>   for travel to any country)

I believe in my case I don't require a transit visa. Can anyone confirm please?

Comment: In the first case your port of entry is not Ottawa but Toronto, and of course you don’t need an additional visa as you already have one for Canada...

Comment: @jcaron: But my PR document says port of entry should be Ottawa. If this is the case, then i think i should opt for 2nd option. am i correct?

Comment: The UK government says you don't need a transit visa. There is nothing left to confirm! As for your port of entry, that means your first arrival city _within Canada_. So you should fly via London.

Comment: Could you expand on why you believe your immigrant visa restricts you to using a particular port of entry? Thatt sounds likely to be a misunderstanding of some sort. Please provide scans/pictures of relevant document, with your personal information blotted out.

Comment: Voting to reopen, because the UK transit question certainly doesn't cover the OP's impression that his existing visa may not be valid for entering Canada at Toronto.

Comment: I think this should be reopened too. I believe that if you get a Skilled Immigrant visa via a provincial nomination you need to tell them the city (and hence province) you'll be working in, but that isn't the same as the port of entry. If there were a constraint on that it would be written on the visa itself(?).

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.